# What is the name of a verse consisting of 7 syllables?

Tags: poetry, syllables, meter

What is the name of a verse consisting of 7 syllables? I thought it was called a *heptameter*, but that seems to be [something different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptameter).

Example:

> I like chocolate cake with pears.

Comment: In English poetry, you only count syllables in haiku. Other languages, like French, count syllables in most forms of poetry. The reason is that English is a stress-timed language, and French is a syllable-timed language.

Comment: You are unfamiliar with sonnets?

Comment: And chocolate might not be *chalk-lit* but *chalk-a-lit* anyway.

Comment: @TheNate Not very familiar, thanks for the information.

Comment: Certainly 7 syllables is not heptameter.  Recall: "iambic pentameter" does not mean 5 syllables; it means 5 feet, each foot being an iamb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In English poetry, the meter is not determined solely by the number of syllables, except in haiku (a form borrowed from another language), so we don't have a word that people use for all lines of verse with seven syllables. Other languages, like French, count syllables in most forms of poetry. The reason is that English is a stress-timed language, and French is a syllable-timed language. This means that in English, the number of stressed syllables in a line is generally more important than the total number of syllables.

Seven-syllable lines in English verse can have several different names.

If you're trying to figure out the meter of a poem like Shakespeare's witches' chants, whose lines have the same pattern of stresses as your example:

> Fillet of a fenny snake,
> In the cauldron boil and bake;
> Eye of newt and toe of frog,
> Wool of bat and tongue of dog,
> Adder's fork and blind-worm's sting,
> Lizard's leg and howlet's wing,

this would be called [catalectic trochaic tetrameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalectic). (Catalectic because, compared with regular trochaic tetrameter, all the lines are missing a syllable at the end.)

On the other hand, the exact same pattern of stresses appears in the first line of Hughes Mearnes poem *Antigonish*:

> Yesterday, upon the stair,
> I met a man who wasn’t there
> He wasn’t there again today
> I wish, I wish he’d go away.

And here, it would be classified as headless [iambic tetrameter,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_tetrameter) because the other lines are all iambic tetrameter.

You can also have seven-syllable lines in iambic trimeter, for example the odd-numbered lines of Housman's poem *When I was One-and-Twenty*, the first verse of which goes:

> When I was one-and-twenty
> I heard a wise man say,
> "Give crowns and pounds and guineas
> But not your heart away;
> Give pearls away and rubies
> But keep your fancy free.”
> But I was one-and-twenty,
> No use to talk to me.

These lines would be called iambic trimeter with a [feminine ending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masculine_and_feminine_endings).

Occasionally, English poets have experimented with syllabic verse in English, where the number of syllables in each line is constant. For example, Dylan Thomas's poem *In my Craft or Sullen Art*, which starts:

> In my craft or sullen art
> Exercised in the still night
> When only the moon rages
> And the lovers lie abed
> With all their griefs in their arms,

There is actually a word in English for lines of poetry with seven syllables, a "heptasyllable". This word is borrowed from French, and is generally only used in analyses of poetry in languages like French, Spanish, and Italian. I can't even find an analysis of Dylan Thomas's poem above where somebody has used it.

Comment: *In English poetry, you only count syllables in haiku*. This strong claim is incorrect; closed form poetry in English is accentual-syllabic, where you count both accents (stressed syllables) and total syllables. If not, terms such as *iamb*, *trochee*, etc. wouldn't apply to English poetry at all; but they're regularly used for analysis. See [this question on Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/16428/289) and the answer provided there. It's no accident that every line in the scanned poem has exactly seven syllables.